# How can I search through a SQL Server database schema to find StoredProcs with a specified set of args?

Tags: sql-server, schema, database-schema, database-metadata

I am trying to deduce which Stored Proc is used to return a specific set of data.

The challenge is that the database has hundreds of Stored Procs. Is there a way I can query the schema to locate all StoredProcs that have parameters named, for instance:

```
Unit
Member
BegDate
EndDate
```

...or, barring that, find SPs that take four args?

That would narrow things down a bit and ameliorate matters.

Comment: Look for PARAMETER_NAME in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`

Comment: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the information you want to find about stored procedures, you can find in tables like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS, SYS.PARAMATERS, SYS.PROCEDURES, SYS.SQL_MODULES, etc.

Your issue can be solved by querying the PARAMETER_NAME in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS.

e.g.

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@Unit'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@Member'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@BegDate'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@EndDate')
SELECT [specific_name] 
FROM T
GROUP BY [specific_name] HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

Or to just find all procedures with 4 parameters:

```
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters GROUP BY [specific_name] HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

Comment: Is the beginning semicolon really supposed to be there? What is its raison d'etre?

Comment: This worked like a champ, although I don't know why (I don't understand the usage of ";" at the beginning or "WITH T". Anyway, I will henceforth think of you as the SQL Server Metadata Whisperer, Zebra Lion Kangaroo.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The semicolon just terminates the previous statement (if there was one). If there wasn't a previous statement, it does nothing (it's harmless). CTEs require the previous statement to be terminated (if there was one).