# How can I query my Database for any Stored Proc that returns a field/column value of a specific name?

Tags: sql-server, schema, database-schema, database-metadata, server-explorer

I want to query the metadata of my Database for any Stored Proc that returns the values from a field or column named "bidprice"

I got a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212973/how-can-i-search-through-a-sql-server-database-schema-to-find-storedprocs-with-a) for how to search for Stored Procs that require a specific set of parameters, namely for Stored Procs that have parameters named Unit, Member, BegDate, and EndDate, this:

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@Unit'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@Member'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@BegDate'
UNION ALL
SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.parameters WHERE [parameter_name] = '@EndDate')
SELECT [specific_name] 
FROM T
GROUP BY [specific_name] HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

That works perfectly; and so I hoped that maybe what I needed to find Stored Procs that return a field/column value of a specific name, such as "bidprice" might be something as simple as this:

```
; SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE [COL_NAME] = "bidprice"
FROM T
```

...but trying it in Visual Studio.Server Explorer (right-clicking on the database connection's Tables folder, and then selecting New Query), I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Is [specific_name] wrong for this type of query?
Is COLUMNS or [COL_NAME] wrong for this type of query?

I also tried to simplify the query this way:

```
; SELECT [specific_name] FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE [COL_NAME] = "bidprice"
```

...but got:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'COL_NAME'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'bidprice'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'specific_name'.
```

(and the same exact err when removing the prepended ";")

What is the right way to search for Stored Procs that return in their result set (among/amidst whatever else) a field/column named "bidprice"?

Comment: information_schema.COLUMNS is NOT used to search return column in stored procedures https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

Comment: I guessed that; what *is* used?

Comment: I don't know if you can really search return columns in stored procedures. I would start with search text in stored procedures with sys.sql_modules  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sp_describe_first_result_set` this returns the metadata from tsql batch. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602%28v=sql.110%29.aspx